# IE removing elements from form/ fieldset

Tags: forms, internet-explorer

I am building an .net mvc app that requires internet explorer 7, 8, 9 and 10 support. The majority of the program works in ie down to 7, but I have a curious issue when using a partial view in IE7 and IE8. If I insert a partial view into a form or fieldset, immediately after the partial finishes, the form/ fieldset is closed, and the rest of the from/ fieldset is displayed after.

This is OK for fieldsets, but data is being removed from my forms, which breaks submissions.

Chrome:
[image: IMG]

IE7:
[image: IMG]

Note that IE7 closes the form just before the javascript, and then ignores the `</form>` later on. Is this an issue with nesting javascript in forms?

Any suggestions?

Comment: `</form/>`? Check HTML.

Comment: Strange - hadn't noticed that. But I am using `@using (Html.BeginForm())`, so I think that extra \ is being added by ie somehow. Chrome and firefox don't have it.

Comment: Let us have a look at the page markup.

Comment: May I suggest running your html code through the [w3c validator](http://validator.w3.org/). If there are any HTML errors in there, that should highlight them.